# R cant find function from third part package without namespace identifier

Tags: r

My app.R files looks like this:

```
library(here)
library(shiny)

getAnalysisApp <- function(appName) {
 script.dir <- here()
 appPath = paste(script.dir, "/R/analysis/", appName,sep = "")

 return (appPath);
}
```

I execute with this in command prompt:

```
R -e "brit::getAnalysisApp('distribution')"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in here() : could not get function "here"
```

if i modify the function call to

```
here::here()
```

the function executes no problem. I cannot write my entire R app using namespaces to address functions! Any ideas what I am missing?

I've even tried the following with roxygen:

```
#' @importFrom here here
#' @export
getAnalysisApp <- function(appName) {
 script.dir <- here()
 appPath = paste(script.dir, "/R/analysis/", appName,sep = "")

 return (appPath);
}
```

With no success.

I am using R studio to build my package and its running:

```
devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
```

To run the build. Then, in my command prompt I am running:

```
R CMD INSTALL package.tar.gz
```

and then executing my function, as mentioned above:

```
R -e "brit::getAnalysisApp('distribution')"
```

Thanks for any help. I've been trying to beat this all day D:

Comment: it seems you have a solution but you don't like it. maybe create a local function `here` which points to here:here

Comment: Do you have here in your IMPORTS line in your DESCRIPTION file?  If you're building a package you shouldn't have any library statements in your code. And you could check to make sure that the NAMESPACE file is generated correctly as well.